# Remove duplicate objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have seen many implementations where people try to remove duplicate items from a javascript array by either looping over the entire array multiple times and searching for indices and checking wether other objects share that index. This seems like a very tedious approach.

I'd rather create a set (I do not care about the order) from the array and convert it back into an array. This approach however does not seem to work for objects. E.g. [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5b6zpxg/) prints the array exactly as it was before. How could I now convert the array from the example in the fiddle EFFICIENTLY to an array filtered on the 'key' variable? (Or any other combination of variables).

```js
const array = [{
    key: 'x',
    value: 0
  },
  {
    key: 'x',
    value: 0
  }
]

console.log(array);

const filtered = Array.from(new Set(array));
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code _in the question itself_ as a [mcve], not behind a link.

Comment: The 'new set' style won't work for array's holding objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
 const filtered = Array.from(new Set(array.map(JSON.stringify))).map(JSON.parse);
    console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This is basically a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66451589/989920 from the duplicate...